# How does symfony solves deadlock situation in dependency injection?

Tags: symfony, events, design-patterns, yii, dependency-injection

I am switching from Yii1 to Symfony3 and would like to know how Symfony solves deadlock situation.

Yii loads user, url managers services automatically on each application load and they are available as `Yii::app()->user`, etc.. I have membership service and it should be loaded every time when user successfully logs in. So I extended Yii user class by adding onAfterLogin signal and set handler for that signal which loads membership service.

The scenario which causes problem is:

1. Yii application creates user class instance
2. If $_SESSION is empty Yii user class looks for user data in cookie and if it is available, it logs user from cookie thus raising onAfterLogin signal.
3. onAfterLogin handler creates membership class
4. In membership class constructor I access `Yii::app()->user`
5. Yii application pushes user class instance into its service array, so that it could be available globally by `Yii::app()->user`

Obviously 4 step raises error because `Yii::app()->user` is not available yet.

Does such problem exists in Symfony? If yes, how is it solved? My case is related with user and membership, but generally those classes may be others.

Comment: Why step 4 cause error if user is logged in? In Symfony you have events system, once user login, you can listen to that event and access user data.

Comment: Because: 1.`$u = new CWebUser`; 5. `$u->init(); Yii::app()->setUser($u)`;

Comment: 1.`$u = new CWebUser; $u->init();` `init` method calls `loginFromCookie` and `loginFromCookie` calls `onAfterLogin`; 5. `Yii::serviceArray['user' => $u]` and now you can call `Yii::app()->user`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question:

1) If it's about dealing with services which may or not exist, Symfony allows to define "optional dependencies". If they don't exist, your application won't break. Read about this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#making-references-optional

2) If the question is specifically about the object that represents the user, Symfony solves this by always providing you a "token" that represents the user, even for anonymous users (`$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()`)